# How to pad a legend in matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, geopandas

I have the following code that uses `GeoPandas` to visualize columns on a shape file

```
cols = ['UrbanPop','Murder','Assault','Rape']

for i in cols:
  fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,12))
  
  merged.plot(column=i,
            ax=ax,
            legend=True,
            legend_kwds={'label': i,
                         'orientation': "horizontal"})
  plt.axis("off")
```

This does exactly what I want, except for the fact that the colorbars are far from their respective shapefile. Is there a a parameter that lets me control this? I figured it might be a `pad` of some sort but I can't get it to work.

`GeoPandas` [documentation](https://geopandas.org/reference.html) says that `legend_kwds()` are "Keyword arguments to pass to matplotlib.pyplot.legend() or matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar()" however, upon checking the documentaion for both of those, I still can't seem to figure it out. I've always had trouble with the parameters for these `x_kwds` parameters, I can't seem to find a list of them in one place. Same for `scatter_kws` and `line_kws` in seaborn.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

What's the version of your `geopandas`? For `0.8.1`, you can simply pass a `pad` arg in `legend_kwds`.

```py
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 5))
legend_kwds = dict(orientation='horizontal', label='Murder', pad=-0.5)
gdf.plot(column='gdp_md_est', legend=True, legend_kwds=legend_kwds, ax=ax)
```

You can check matplotlib doc [here](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html)

[image]